# why need to use virtual and override?

Tags: c#

i have created same name methods in base and derived classes and i am able to create

```
class Program
{
    public void CalculateArea(int a,int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a*b);
    }
}
class progrmm1:Program
{
    public void CalculateArea(int a ,int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        progrmm1 obj = new progrmm1();
        Program obj1 = new Program();
        obj.CalculateArea(4,5);
        obj1.CalculateArea(4,5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

then why i need to use virtual and override

Comment: You need to override because in your inherited class you change the output of the `CalculateArea` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use `virtual` and `override` then you are not taking advantage of polymorphism.  Basically the `CalculateArea` in the derived class is hiding the one in the base class.  That means that if you reference an object of the derived class type as the base it will call the `CalculateArea` in the base class instead of the derived one.  Where as if you use `virtual` and `override` it would call the Derived method even if it where referenced as the Base.

For example with these classes

```
public class Base
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoSomething");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoSomething");
    }
}
```

This code

```
Base derivedAsBase = new Derived();
derivedAsBase.DoSomething();
```

will output

> Base.DoSomething

but using `virtual` and `override`

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoSomething");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoSomething");
    }
}
```

The same code

```
Base derivedAsBase = new Derived();
derivedAsBase.DoSomething();
```

will output

> Derived.DoSomething

Answer (score 0):

When overridden, the method on the most derived class is called. Observe this slightly modified code where I assign two Program instances. One from a Program and one from a program1:

```
class Program
{
    public virtual void CalculateArea(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a * b);
    }
}
class progrmm1 : Program
{
    public override void CalculateArea(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new progrmm1();
        Program obj1 = new Program();

        obj.CalculateArea(4, 5);
        obj1.CalculateArea(4, 5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

9

20

And now, observe non-virtual:

```
class Program
{
    public void CalculateArea(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a * b);
    }
}
class progrmm1 : Program
{
    public void CalculateArea(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new progrmm1();
        Program obj1 = new Program();

        obj.CalculateArea(4, 5);
        obj1.CalculateArea(4, 5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

20

20

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know about Virtual Method.

- Basically A virtual method is a method that can be redefined in
  derived classes. A virtual method has an implementation in a base
  class as well as derived the class.

**Example**:
Let Suppose we have two classes, A and B. Class A has a public virtual method called Test. Class B, meanwhile, derives from class A and it provides a public override method called Test as well.

```
using System;
class A
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("A.Test");
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override void Test()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("B.Test");
    }
}
class Program
{
     static void Main()
     {
       // Compile-time type is A.
       // Runtime type is A as well.
       A ref1 = new A();
       ref1.Test();

       // Compile-time type is A.
       // Runtime type is B.
       A ref2 = new B();
       ref2.Test();
     }
}
```

> **Output**

- > A.Test
- > B.Test

**Why would you need to use virtual methods?**:
Your program may be designed in such a way that you do not know all the types of objects that will occur when it is executed. You can provide a standard (base) type and design around that type.
Then, you can re-implement important functionality depending on the more specific (derived) types. When you call a method on the base type, you invoke the more derived (and useful) method.